Is it possible to swap the most significant bit and the least significant bit of a register in x86 assembly without using conditional jumps?
Here is how it is done in PicoBlaze assembly:
;This is an example program written by
;Agustin Izaguirre in the issue #9. It
;switches the least significant bit and the
;most significant bit without using jumps.

address 0

load s0,59
output s0,0

;shift and load MSB into an aux register
sl0 s0
output s0, 0
addcy s1, 0

;shift back again and load LSB into an aux register
sr0 s0
output s0, 0
sr0 s0
output s0, 0
addcy s2, 0

;load MSB aux reg into carry so that we can SLA in the bit
sr0 s1
sla s0
output s0, 0

;shift back and load LSB aux reg into carry so that we can SRA in the bit
sl0 s0
output s0, 0
sr0 s2
sra s0 ;bugged line, should be shifting the C flag from the left
output s0, 0

Is it possible to do that in x86 assembly as well? If so, how?
x86 has no equivalent of the sra instruction, right? So, how can it be simulated without using conditional jumps?

x86 has a rich set of shift & rotate instructions.  But you don't need some clever assembly to do this, it can be done in C or Java without conditional logic.

For 32 bit input I, output O = ( I & 7ffffffe) | (I << 31) | (I >> 31).

You've asked the same question on reddit a few hours ago and I provided you with an answer.  What is it that you are missing?

Here's a simple way to do it, assuming eax holds AXX...XB initially:
rol eax, 1 ; EAX = XXX...XBA, CF = A
bt  eax, 1 ; EAX = XXX...XBA, CF = B
rcr eax, 2 ; EAX = ABXXX...X, CF = B
rol eax, 1 ; EAX = BXXX...XA, CF = A


If you want to exchange MSB and LSB (or for that matter, any other bit) in EAX.
pushf               ;Save FLAGS
push ebx            ;Save EBX - used as temp register.
xor  ebx, ebx       ;Set EBX to 0.
bt   eax, 0         ;Move EAX[0] to carry.
setc bl             ;Set BL according to carry.
ror  ebx, 1         ;Rotate EBX right to move LSB to MSB
bt   eax, 31        ;Move EAX[31] to carry.
setc bl             ;Set BL according to carry. 
and  eax, 0x7FFFFFFE;Set EAX[31] and EAX[0] to 0 (bitmask 0b1…30x0…1 = 0x7FFFFFFE).
xor  eax, ebx       ;Set EAX[31] and EAX[0] to EBX[31] and EBX[0], therefore to EAX[0] and EAX[31].
pop  ebx            ;Restore EBX.
popf                ;Restore FLAGS.


I think the AND needs to use 0x7FFFFFFE. You used two Es.

You are right, thanks, I just corrected the mistake.

xor  ebx, ebx clears the Carry Flag so you mustn't put it immediately before setc

I see, thanks, I accidentally swapped the lines while copying. Already fixed.
